# Add own table to CRM 2011 database

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm writing a CRM 2011 plugin which needs to create a custom number for each new entity.
My idea is to add a custom table (whithout any relation to other tables) to the CRM 2011 database which I can use to store/read/change my custom number.

Is this a good way to store custom information in database or shouldn't I use the CRM 2011 database for that?
I can't use external databases because of the CRM online sandbox limitations...

thanks
Tobi

Comment: What's the Custom Number for?

Answer (score 2):

It's not supported to make changes to the CRM 2011 SQL database.

Instead you can create a custom entity inside CRM 2011 with two fields:

- Entity Name
- Number

so the records will look like as

```
account | 23
contact | 112
```

and you can use the CRM 2011 Web Services to manage these values, in this way all your code is supported and works also with CRM Online.

Comment: thanks a lot! so there is now other way to store individual Information? in sandbox I don't have Access to the filesystem and no Access to other databases right?

Comment: no other way, and as confirmed by James Wood  it's a common practice to create simple entities to store values.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of adding a table to the database I'm going to assume you mean, 'I will create a new entity in CRM and CRM will then create a table in the database for me'. As creating a table directly in the database is unsupported (and not possible in CRM Online in any case).

Creating an entity to store 'settings' information is perfectly acceptable and is practised by myself and many other CRM consultants.

It sounds like you are implementing some sort of auto number tool, so a quick word of warning. In CRM this is inherently tricky because there is no easy locking, e.g. if two records generate at the same time they can both end up with the same number.

I would suggest having a read of this, which suggests a method for locking effectively.

[Implementing Robust Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Auto-Numbering Using Transactions](http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2012/01/implementing-robust-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-auto-numbering-using-transactions/)

Comment: yes I wanted to just create a table without any entity-relation or any relation to another table. But if this is not possible I have to find another way. I want to write a plugin that creates an individual number. Maybe a stored procedure with isolation level "Serializable" can handle that. I will try to create an entity like you descriped!

Comment: In CRM, creating an entity creates a table in the database, CRM is the interface through which you access the database.